# Maven: module shared by multiple projects?

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have multiple projects that depends on the same data model. The latter is defined by a Maven project. Let's take as example two composite projects A and B that include multiple modules each one and that depend on this data model. The project A and B are not related.

What is the best approach in this case? To leave the data model as an independent project with A and B depending on it? Or, to define the data model as a module and to include it in the two composite projects A and B (I don't know if a module may be shared by many projects)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "maven way", especially since projects A and B are unrelated, would be to create a 3rd project for the shared code. It would have its own artifact id and version (separate from A and B).

When I do this I use the [`maven-release-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) to tag it and deploy it to my Maven repository server ([Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)). If you aren't working this way you can manually build it and it will go in your local repository. When you build the other projects it will resolve.